# How does sorting in c++ work?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm a Java developer. I'm currently learning C++. I've been looking at code samples for sorting. In Java, one normally gives a sorting method the container it needs to sort e.g

```
sort(Object[] someArray)
```

I've noticed in C++ that you pass two args, the start and end of the container. My question is that how is the actual container accessed then?

Here's sample code taken from Wikipedia illustrating the the sort method

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main() {
 std::vector<int> vec;
 vec.push_back(10); vec.push_back(5); vec.push_back(100); 
 std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
 for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) 
     std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Learn about [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) in C++. They will help you understand everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vec.begin()` and `vec.end()` are returning iterators iterators. The iterators are kind of pointers on the elements, you can read them and modify them using iterators. That is what sort is doing using the iterators.

If it is an iterator, you can directly modify the object the iterator is referring to:

```
*it = X;
```

The sort function does not have to know about the containers, which is the power of the iterators. By manipulating the pointers, it can sort the complete container without even knowing exactly what container it is.

You should learn about iterators (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html)

Answer (score 2):

`vec.begin()` and `vec.end()` do not return the first and last elements of the `vector`. They actually return what is known as an *iterator*. An iterator behaves very much like a pointer to the elements. If you have an iterator `i` that you initialised with `vec.begin()`, you can get a pointer to the second element in the vector just by doing `i++` - the same as you would if you had a point to the first element in an array. Likewise you can do `i--` to go backwards. For some iterators (known as random access iterators), you can even do `i + 5` to get an iterator to the 5th element after `i`.

This is how the algorithm accesses the container. It knows that all of the elements that it should be sorting are between `begin()` and `end()`. It navigates around the elements by doing simple iterator operations. It can then modify the elements by doing `*i`, which gives the algorithm a reference to the element that `i` is pointing at. For example, if `i` is set to `vec.begin()`, and you do `*i = 5;`, you will change the value of the first element of `vec`.

This approach allows you to pass only *part* of a `vector` to be sorted. Let's say you only wanted to sort the first 5 elements of your `vector`. You could do:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + 5);
```

This is very powerful. Since iterators behave very much like pointers, you can actually pass plain old pointers too. Let's say you have an array `int array[] = {4, 3, 2, 5, 1};`, you could easily call `std::sort(array, array + 5)` (because the name of an array will decay to a pointer to its first element).

Comment: That actually makes sense."because the name of an array will decay to a pointer to its first element", I think that's actually the case with MIPS assembly code too --- Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The container doesn't *have* to be accessed. That's the whole point of the design behind the Standard Template Library (which became part of the C++ standard library): The algorithms don't know anything about containers, just iterators.

This means they can work with anything that provides a pair of iterators. Of course all STL containers provide `begin()` and `end()` methods, but you can also use a regular old C array, or an MFC or glib container, or anything else, just by writing your own iterators for it. (And for C arrays, it's as simple as `a` and `a+a_len` for the begin and end iterators.)

As for how it works under the covers: Iterators follow an implicit protocol: you can do things like `++it` to advance an iterator to the next element, or `*it` to get the value of the current element, or `*it = 3` to set the value of the current element. (It's a bit more complicated than this, because there are a few different protocols—iterators can be random-access or forward-only, const or writable, etc. But that's the basic idea.) So, if `sort is coded to restrict itself to the iterator protocol (and, of course, it is), it works with anything that conforms to that protocol.

To learn more, there are many tutorials on the internet (and in the bookstore); there's only so much an SO answer can explain.

Comment: Of course it has to be "accessed". What the asker doesn't understand is how it is accessed.

Comment: @PedroLamarão: The container itself is _not_ accessed; only the data inside the container is accessed. That's why you have to, e.g., call `erase` after `remove`.

Comment: Your interpretation of "access" won't help you communicate with the asker.

Comment: @PedroLamarão: If the OP doesn't get the distinction now, he will have a serious misunderstanding that will cause subtle problems until it finally comes to the surface when he needs the erase-remove idiom and has to learn what he's been getting wrong all this time. Better to explain it at the start.

Answer (score 0):

`begin()` and `end()` return iterators.  See e.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html

Answer (score 0):

Iterators act like references into part of a container.  That is, `*iter = z;` actually changes one of the elements in the container.

`std::sort` actually uses a `swap` function on references to the contained objects, so that any iterators you have already initialized remain in the same order but the values those iterators refer to are changed.

Note that `std::list` also has member functions called `sort`.  It works the other way around: any iterators you have already initialized keep the same values, but the order of those iterators changes.